# Capturar Tempo de Abertura de Script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Olá, pessoal.

Estou tentando criar um projeto, cujo a função é identificar o tempo que a página está aberta (ex: se ficou 1 ou 2 minutos aberta). Quando for fechada, salvar no banco de dados as informações de tempo.

Porém, sou uma negação com javascript, jquery e afins.
Segue código de exemplo:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var aberturaPagina;
  $(window).ready(function () {
    aberturaPagina = new Date().getTime();
  });
  $(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
    var fechoPagina = new Date().getTime();
    var tempoAberto = (fechoPagina - aberturaPagina) / 1000;

    $.ajax({
      type : "POST",
      url : "http://url.exmplo.com.br/codigo_db.php?id=1&tempo=" + tempoAberto,
        sucess : function(html){
        $('.div').html(html);
      }
    })
  });
</script>
```

Ao executar a página, nada acontece!

Eu montei esse frankenstein com códigos de alguns fóruns, alguém pode me ajudar a corrigir?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Os navegadores ignoram requisições assíncronas iniciadas no evento unload. Existem ao menos duas formas de contornar isso: fazer uma  **requisição síncrona** ou usar a API **navigator.sendBacon**. Esta última não é suportada no IE 11 mas tem a vantagem de ser assíncrona e por tanto não bloquear o navegador durante a duração da consulta.

Exemplo com requisição síncrona:

```js
var aberturaPagina;

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  aberturaPagina = new Date().getTime();
});

window.addEventListener('unload', function () {
  var fechoPagina = new Date().getTime();
  var tempoAberto = (fechoPagina - aberturaPagina) / 1000;
  var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
  client.open('POST', 'http://requestb.in/1a4i8zc1', false);
  client.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  client.send('id=1&tempo=' + tempoAberto);
}, true);
```

Exemplo com sendBeacon:

```js
var aberturaPagina;

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  aberturaPagina = new Date().getTime();
});

window.addEventListener('unload', function () {
  var fechoPagina = new Date().getTime();
  var tempoAberto = (fechoPagina - aberturaPagina) / 1000;
  navigator.sendBeacon('http://requestb.in/1a4i8zc1', 'id=1&tempo=' + tempoAberto);
}, true);
```

**Referência**

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon

Comment: Perfeito! Muito obrigado.
Funcionou com requisição síncrona